# Развертывание проекта на Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, maven, tomcat

*Здравствуйте*,

Сейчас я пытаюсь развернуть maven проект при помощи tomcat но получаю ошибку:

Когда я ввожу команду:

`mvn tomcat7:deploy`

Получаю:

`Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]`

Есть этот плагин в **pom.xml**:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <server>tomcatserver</server>
      <path>/</path>
      <port>8000</port>
      <update>true</update>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>tomcat</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Также настроены следующие роли и пользователи в **tomcat-users.xml**:

```xml
<!-- My roles -->
  <role rolename="tomcat"></role>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"></role>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"></role>
  <role rolename="manager-script"></role>

<!-- My users -->
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui,manager-script"/>
  <user username="fedotsoldier" password="010702" roles="manager-script,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Это мой **settings.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>tomcatserver</id>
      <username>tomcat</username>
      <password>tomcat</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Полный вывод ошибки:

```bsh
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-23T18:10:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webproject: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project webproject: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:591)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket (PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection (DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open (ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect (DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute (DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute (AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke (TomcatManager.java:742)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl (TomcatManager.java:705)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy (TomcatManager.java:388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar (AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager (AbstractDeployMojo.java:82)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute (AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Ни один из прочитанных мной на других сайтах советов не помог.

Что я делаю не так? Как мне запустить мой maven веб-проект по адресу http://localhost:8000 ?

---

**UPD**:

Проект работает по нужному адресу при вводе команды `mvn tomcat7:run`.

Чем же она хуже `mvn tomcat7:deploy`? Чем они отличаются?

Comment: Возможно порт <port>8000</port> должен совпадать с тем, который в  урл <url>localhost:8080/manager/text</url>

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Пропиши в `<build>`

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

Очевидно, что это

```
<port>8000</port>
<username>tomcat</username>
<password>tomcat</password>
```

лишнее, и замени `<path>/</path>` на

```
<path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
```

остальное вроде в порядке

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Давайте обсудим ваши предложения.


1. Зачем мне прописывать в `<build>` тэг <finalName` как `${project.artifactId}`? Может я хочу задать своё имя? Не могли бы вы объяснить на что влияет этот тэг `<finalName>` в файле **pom.xml**?


2. Явное указание порта - `<port>8000</port>` лишним не является, тк, даже если я пропишу `<url>` как `http://localhost:8000/manager/text`, при запуске приложение все равно заработает на порту `8080` с соответствующей корректировкой url адреса, по которому будет доступно моё приложение.

Comment: 3. Зачем заменять мой тэг `<path>` на `/${project.build.finalName}`? Ведь я хочу, чтобы мое приложение было доступно именно на `../localhost`, а не на `../localhost/${project.build.finalName}/`.

4. Про сервер совсем не понял. Что вы имеете в виду под словом *"магический"*?) Чем это название магическое? Почему я должен использовать его, а не то имя, которое мне удобно?

Comment: P.S. Смена имени сервера на *магическое "tomcat7"* не помогла

Comment: Проект работает по нужному адресу при вводе команды `mvn tomcat7:run`. Чем же она хуже `mvn tomcat7:deploy`? Чем они отличаются?

Comment: Да, с именем сервера, я конечно, напутал, оно должно соответствовать, идентификатору из настроек мавена. Что касается пути для приложения, то смысл его указания в том, что `/` по умолчанию занят, это каталог ROOT. `run` - создает отдельное окружение - свой `webapps` (физически, где-нибудь в темповом каталоге и без рута), деплоит war и запускает приложение. `deploy` - деплоит war в "родное" для тома окружение и запускает приложение

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо за объяснение.
А почему вы не согласны с необходимостью указания `<port>8000</port>`(не удалили из вашего ответа)? Ведь без него по умолчанию запускается на 8080 порту.

Comment: И зачем создавать отдельный тэг `finalName` в `build`? Почему сразу в тэге `path` не прописать `${project.artifactId}`?

Comment: Я пытаюсь выполнить команду `mvn tomcat7:deploy` при указанном и незанятом по вашей логике пути `/${project.artifactId}`. При этом все равно получаю `Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection refused (Connection refused)`